# Can parsing be classified to some complexity class (e.g. NP-complete)?

Tags: computational-linguistics, nlp, parsing, computer-science

In computer science (especially [computational complexity theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory)), problems can be classified to some complexity theory. For example, we say the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) belongs to NP-complete.

Parsing of a human-language text (e.g. English text) is also a computational problem. Can it be analyzed and classified to some complexity class? If yes, which class does it belong to and why?

Comment: This recent blog post by Bob Berwick on computational complexity and minimalism might be of interest to you: http://facultyoflanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/minimalism-and-computational-complexity_19.html

Answer (score 1):

While I have been unable to find any excerpts from the book in question, ["A Fundamental Algorithm for Dependency Parsing"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.7335&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by M. Covington references ["Computational Complexity And Natural Language"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/computational-complexity-and-natural-language) by Barton, Berwick, and Ristad, saying:

> Barton, Berwick and Ristad... prove that when lexical ambiguity and agreement features are present — that is, when words can be ambiguous and can be labeled with attributes — natural language parsing is NP-complete.

I suspect this book may be of great interest to you.

This conclusion is backed up by ["Computational complexity of problems on probabilistic grammars and transducers."](http://pagesperso.lina.univ-nantes.fr/~cdlh/papers/icgi.stringmax.pdf) by F. Casacuberta et al. which provides proofs that parsing of Stochastic Regular Grammars is NP-Hard as well as ["Generation as Dependency Parsing"](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P02/P02-1003.pdf) by A. Koller et al. which offers an ad hoc proof that parsing Topological Dependency Grammars is also NP-complete. As well as several other papers I found with a quick search on Google Scholar.

Comment: The reason is that parsing per se -- i.e, only syntactic parsing -- produces multiple ambiguities that are usually resolved in practice by semantic, pragmatic, metaphorical, or local personal conventions. I.e, [statistics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/abney95c.pdf).

Comment: The paper by Berwick is at www.aclweb.org/anthology-new/J/J82/J82-3001.pdf, in case you want to update your link.

Comment: This is not a criticism of what you wrote, but Berwick ends his paper in an uncertain tone. (I have only skimmed it, so I might be wrong.) But papers that cite this seem to make it sound like Berwick established a proof.

Comment: @prash The paper I'm quote is actually citing a textbook, not the paper you link. Perhaps the textbook contains an actual proof? I suspect that there are too many variations across languages to say in a general case whether parsing natural languages is in any complexity class. But the original question sparked my interest and this answer is just a collection of the papers I found helpful.

Comment: @prash From what I read, this Berwick's paper only shows that LFG is NP-hard. It seems that there is a later proof that it is NP-complete.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the framework. Within LFG, parsing is NP-compete in the worst case. However, Ron Kaplan argues that NL parsing is polynomial in the average case. In general, NL parsing is NP-complete because of the constraints associated with rules.

Comment: As you said, parsing complexity depends on the framework. Some
frameworks can be very powerful, beyond NP-completeness, though that
is bad enough. For many years it was known that LFG were NP-hard, and
it took some time to prove that its complexity is limited to
NP-completeness.

Comment: @babou Do you know who proved it? LFG parsing can be translated into SAT but I guess the original proof was different.

Comment: I think the reference is easily found on the web. There ar several of them. But I do not remember off hand. I was traveling for a while, hence late answer. If you do not find it ask again, I will look. http://ai.ato.ms/MITECS/Entry/dalrymple.html => *It has been shown that LFG recognition is NP-complete (Berwick 1982)* : Berwick, R. (1982). Computational complexity and Lexical Functional Grammar. American Journal of Computational Linguistics 8:97-109.

Comment: Maybe look at: `download\?doi\=10.1.1.119.776\&rep\=rep1\&type\=pdf`  Unification-based grammars and complexity classes, Anders Søgaard

Comment: @babou Thanks, the references in Søgaard's paper are very helpful.

Comment: Does this mean our human brains can solve these NP Complete problems in P time? Or at least if not always, to a very good approximation? What implications, if any, does this have for questions concerning theses on the computing power (in terms of complexity, not speed) of the physical universe (since our brains are physical objects)?

Comment: @mike3 Sort of. The human mind excels at abductive reasoning and all natural language processing happens by what's usually called weighted abduction, whose complexity is worse (sic!) than NP-complete. Since weighted means probabilistic in this context, it's always an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

*Preliminary note: I tried to be as general as possible, but the variety of
syntactic descriptions of Natural Language is such that it is unlikely
that everyone will find here his preferred brand of syntax or parsing. For example, the parsing of lexicalized descriptions of language is not directly accounted for. I am not sure that this
can be helped in any reasonnable way. My purpose here has been mainly to explore the range of questions that could or should be addressed when considering the complexity of natural language parsing.*

The first point is that "*Parsing of a human-language text*" is an ill defined task. Complexity analysis is a mathematical endeavor which makes sense only within a mathematically well defined framework. You can therefore ask such a question only with respect to a given formal description of the language syntax.

Another preliminary point is that parsing is supposed to analyze syntax only, not semantics. But where is the border between syntax and semantics.

**What is parsing ?**

Parsing is always done with respect to a grammar (term used loosely to
mean a description of the syntax) of a language in some appropriate
formalism (formal framework). So the complexity classes are also
classifying these formalisms.

Secondly, the concept of parsing itself should be precisely defined,
It is clear that it is an algorithm taking as input a sentence
(meaning only a linear sequence of words) and produces as output a
structure that give a more explicit description of the sentence
emphisizing the structural properties that make it belong to the language specified by the given
grammar (I am trying very hard not to be too specific).

For example, with a generative grammar, the output of the parsing
process may be a structure that describes precisely how the sentence
can be generated by that grammar, when it is syntactically correct,
i.e. when it belongs to the language described.

Furthermore, it is known that natural languages are generally
syntactically ambiguous, i.e., that some syntactically correct
sentences can be structurally described in several ways (generated in
differents ways). Note that a sentence can be syntactically ambiguous,
even though there is no semantic ambuiguity.  Now the result expected
from parsing could be :

- just be a yes/no answer stating whether the sentence is syntactically
  correct. This is usually called *recognition*, rather than parsing;
- any of the possible structural descriptions of the input sentence;
  when it is syntactically correct.
- all the structural descriptions of the input sentence; when it is
  syntactically correct.  This itself opens a spectrum of possibilities
  as there may be different ways of representing this (possibly
  infinite) set of parses, which may be more space efficient or easier
  to use for later stages of the sentence analysis.  See for example
  the question [Is there a favoured data structure for storing ambiguous parse trees in Natural Language Processing?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/) ;
- one or more structural descriptions of the input sentence, when it is
  syntactically correct, satisfying some preference or selection
  criterion.

In addition, the nature of the expected structural description may
vary. Typically, the result of parsing a sentence according to a [tree
adjoining grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree-adjoining_grammar) (TAG) can be a (set of) derivation(s) tree(s) or a
(set of) derived tree(s). Derivation trees and derived trees are
distinct for TAG.

It is not obvious that the complexity is the same for all choices of
what is expected as parsing result for a given formalism.

**What is complexity ?**

If the formalisms, and the result expected from the parsing process,
are properly defined, it is of course possible to classify the parsing
process for that formalism of in some complexity class, or more
precisely to do a complexity analysis of the parsing process, as
complexity classes come in many flavors : time complexity or space
complexity, asymptotic worst case complexity or average complexity.

Though people often think of asymptotic worst case time complexity, it
may make more sense in practice to consider average complexity. So
such clssifications into complexity classes should be interpreted with
care from a pragmatic point of view.

Another point is that complexity is often considered with respect to
the size (number of words) of the sentence to be parsed. But
complexity may also be analyzed with respect to the size of the
grammar used to analyze a sentence. This is important as some people
tend to increase the size of the syntax description in order to
capture rarer or more subtle phenomena. This does not come for free.

Many formalisms are composed of a formal generative skeleton (such as
context-free grammars) where various attributes (features,
probabilities, ...) can be associated to the rules constituents,
having to respect various constraints associated to the rule. The
addition of these attributes and the respect of these constraints
increases, often drastically, the complexity of the formalism, making
it NP-hard, and even possibly Turing-complete (allowing you to encode
as a parsing problem any algorithm you can dream of).

Of course there are zillions of subcases providing interesting
complexity problems to people inclined to such studies.

One aspect commonly analyzed is the complexity of skeleton formalisms,
without any attribute. Typically parsing context-free languages has
time complexity O(n³), which is fairly low and quite tractable in
practice. However, some structural organizations of the sentences
cannot be captured by CF grammar. A classical example is [cross-serial
dependency](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~shieber/Biblio/Papers/shieber85.pdf).

Rather than add attributes to somehow encode the information necessary
to handle such structures in a very general feature mechanism, some
scientists consider that it is more effective, and possibly more
perspicuous, to complexify a bit the skeleton formalism. This for
example lead to the development of Tree Adjoining Grammars (time
complexity O(n⁶)), then to a hierarchy of formalisms with increasing
polynomial complexity, and the so-called [mildly context-sensitive
formalisms](http://www.kornai.com/MatLing/mcsfin.pdf) and  [Linear Context-Free rewriting
systems](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P92/P92-1018.pdf).  One remarkable aspect is that, though the polynomial
worst-case complexity may seem high, structures producing high
complexity may be few, so that things remain very tractable in
practice.

This is to underscore, again, that  complexity analysis
does not necessarily tell the whole story.