# Is there a favoured data structure for storing ambiguous parse trees in Natural Language Processing?

Tags: nlp, parsing, ambiguity

I know a bit about parsing computer languages. Generally they try to resolve all ambiguities when parsing or abort the parse and throw an error.

This means you either got nothing because there was an error, or you have a neat syntax tree / AST with no ambiguities.

Of course in natural languages ambiguity is rampant and has to be handled somehow.

Since the same kind of syntax tree used for computer languages could not work for natural languages ("can" in an ambiguous sentence might be part of a verb phrase or part of a noun phrase depending how you look at it) **I'm wondering if there is some data structure which has gained wide acceptance among NLP practitioners.**

A simplistic obvious approach is just to have one tree for each way of parsing a sentence, but the longer the sentence and the more ambiguities, they tend to compound and everything quickly gets out of hand.

I'm expecting there is some kind of multidimensional tree used which is "flat" in the unambiguous parts of a sentence but has extra layers for each variant parse just in the ambiguous sections. Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same kind of syntax tree used for computer
languages could not work for natural languages"? Actually they are
the same (if you use the same type of grammar in both cases,
context-free being the most comon case). Or do you simply mean that
ambiguity is not dealt with in computer languages, which is both
unfortunate and not completely true?

Comment: Computer languages parsers either stop and report an error or chose one interpretation as defined by the language. They don't store all ambiguities into an AST for the next stage to analyse.

Comment: Still the same kinds of AST are used in both cases. And some computer
languages (ADA for example) do allow for a little syntactic ambiguity,
which may or may not be resolved on a semantic basis, but I do not
recall how implementations handle it. The compiler reports an error
when it cannot resolve the ambiguity (which usually calls for a type cast
in an expression). ASTs cannot store ambiguity, but they can combine into
a structure that, in general, is no longer a tree (it is a grammar).
BTW, was my answer understandable?

Comment: It is not simply a data structure often called **shared forest**, but it has actually a well known
theoretical name. **It is called a grammar** and belongs to the same
class as the grammar used for parsing. See my answer.

Comment: I had half forgotten that I'd already asked here when I later asked a very similar question on Stack Overflow : [Algorithms or data structures for dealing with ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903007)

Comment: I wrote a fairly complete answer to this new question (though I had to keep it within
limits), and added some more references. But this new question makes me wonder what was
wrong, missing, or unconvincing with my previous answers, particularly with the one I give below. Also, I wonder why you ask
on stackoverflow rather than cs.stackexchange or
cstheory.stackexchange. Discussing science on stackoverflow does not feel very effective.

Comment: @babou: Your answers are great, there's just a lot for me to grok. I ask on StackOverflow because the StackExchange staff have previously said that's the place for it but with the other extant sites it is pretty hard to know where to post them. I don't really participate on cs or cstheory because I lack most of the theory/math/etc. I'm just an interested amateur self-taught computer programmer with no formal training. I read those sites but I don't think they'd welcome my too-newbie questions.

Comment: Writing a meaningful answer to your rather general stackoverflow
question was considerable work, and I still catch minor points that
should be amended. But it seems it will get no readership. So, what is
the point?  What is it that you cannot grok? Take a small parse tree
for a string w. Add subscripts to all non-terminals so that they are
all different, Then make a copy of each node with label Ak and
daughters Bi Cj (I assume it is binary) and rewrite it Ak ⟶Bi Cj. You
get a set of CF rules for a grammar that generate only w with
precisely that parse tree. Does this help?

Comment: Don't feel negative, I'm sure people will read this, especially people that find it via Googling ambiguous NLP - I found Stack Exchange by Googling programming questions. There's little entry-level/overview/lay stuff on this topic. A lot is full of algebra and such that untrained but interested people can't read so your answers fill the gap. I'm trying to take a lot in, I have over 50 tabs open with partly read partly digested papers on related topics. Many key topics don't even have Wikipedia articles or SO tags or didn't until I made or requested them (-: I've voted up all your answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Short answer

There is a favoured structure for storing ambiguous parse trees.  It
is usually called a **shared forest**, and **it is simply a grammar that
generates only the sentence parsed with exactly the same parse trees**
as the grammar of the language (up to a renaming homomorphisme for the non-terminal symbols). This applies to Context-Free grammars,
but also to several other formalisms such as Tree-Adjoining Grammars.
It can be used as a generator to enumerate the individual parse-trees.

Shared forests are often presented as a graphs, with various
qualification, but these graphs are only representations of grammars.
**They appear in all general context-free parsers in the literature**.

### Longer answer

Your question is a good question. However, the sentence you emphasize
in boldface is, in my opinion, the wrong way to worry about
representing ambiguity, even though it is the usual way to state it.

When you ask for a data structure, you are asking for a device to do
processing, but you forget to worry about the intrinsic nature of that
device, about the meaning it may have in your model of language
processing. In some sense you emphasize the doing over the understanding.

There is actually an abstract answer that applies to numerous cases,
numerous formalisms, independently of the parsing algorithm used, such
as the CKY algorithm, Earley's algorithm, and many others.

The relevant concept is that of a **shared forest**. It is a condensed
form of all the correct parse trees for the sentence, However, though
the concept of shared forest was widely used in the parsing
literature, it did take some time to understand what it was, other than a convenient data structure. The understanding opened it to generalizations.

Here I am skipping several fine points, see my [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7374/#18006) to another [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7374/), for more details.

The basic idea (described in a [1995 paper by Lang](https://www.academia.edu/798690/Recognition_can_be_harder_than_parsing) and in the [Grune-Jacobs book](http://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_2nd_Edition)) relies on the fact that context-free languages, and
many other syntactic formalisms are closed under intersection with
[regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) (Type-3 grammars in Chomsky hierarchy). Furthermore, this closure property is constructive,
which means that given a grammar G (in some syntactic formalism, such
as CF grammar, or tree adjoining grammar, or many others) generating all syntactically
correct sentences of the language, and a formal specification R of the regular
language, it is possible to exhibit another grammar F, that generates
only the syntactically correct sentences that belong to the regular
set, with exactly the same ambiguities as with the original grammar G. This
grammar F is a shared forest (there are many *equivalent* ways of building such a grammar - see [Billot & Lang, *The structure of shared forests in ambiguous parsing*](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=981641)). Basically, the relevant rules of the original grammar are homomorphique images of the rules of the shared forest, through a renaming homomorphism of the non terminals. The shared forest uses "specialized copies" of the non-terminals of the original grammar so as to control more tightly the generative power of its rules.

A set of one sentence is a regular set, and the construction
applies. Then, the shared forest F can be used a a generative grammar
that generates only a single sentence, but with differents parse-trees
corresponding to all the parses with the original grammar G. So, for example, it can be used to enumerate all the correct parse-trees for the sentence.

This can generalize to many situations. For example, when there is
phonological ambiguity, as in the question
[Phonological ambiguity that changes the syntactic structure](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/), this ambiguity
regarding the words actually uttered can be represented by a word
lattice, which actually defines formally a regular set of (not
necessarily syntactically correct) sentences.
The same construction intersecting the regular set with the grammar G
can be used, accounting at the same time for lexical/phonological
ambiguity and for syntactic ambiguity.

Now, what about this construction of the intersection. For CF
grammars, there is an old construction that was published some 50
years ago ([Bar-Hillel, Perles, Shamir 1961](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/25000219?uid=3738016&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104717280497)). All later algorithms, such as CKY, Earley, chart parsing,
etc, that produce a shared forest are actually only variants of that
construction that may optimize some steps so as to avoid some useless
construction steps while producing the shared forest F. Similar
constructions exist for many other classes of grammar than the CF
grammars.

The next issue is to develop techniques to choose the right tree in
the forest. This can be achieved in various ways but remains a very
open topic. For example it is possible to associate features or data
with specific algebraic characteristics (semi-ring) to the lexicon and
parts of speech, together with composition rules associated to the
grammar rules, to identify the "better" parse-tree. The Viterbi
techniques to chose a most-likely parse-tree according to some
probabilities fall in this category. Alternatively, the choice of
correct parse-trees may be postponed to later stages of analysis.

This is (the skeleton of) the whole story, afaik, regarding shared
forest. Much is still being developped on that basis.

It may seem too abstract, but it gives a good and actually simple
mathematical understanding for organizing the technology. But that
does not mean that all is simple when you get into actual details, for
example with sophisticated feature structures.

Another advantage of the approach is that it gives a cleaner view of
issues by separating the operational from the denotational. What this
means is that the relevant entities you may be interested in, such as
trees or forests, are specified by abstract mathematical definitions,
on the basis of desirable properties, without specifying any actual
method to effectively compute them. The operational algorithms that
will compute them (the parsing algorithms) are elaborated separately,
and have to be proved correct with respect to the denotational
definition. This separates the issues of conceptual perspicuity and
computational correctness and effectiveness.

Another point is that the complexity of the relevant structures can be analyzed from the mathematical definitions, independently of the algorithms that computes them.

Finally, to come back to your question, shared forest have gained wide acceptance among NLP practitioners. The abstract view of it as the grammar of an intersection is less well known by those who are not mathematically oriented, though it is nearly 20 years old. This ignorance/rejection of mathematics is unfortunately the source of much waste of time and energy.

Of course, the grammar view of the shared forest is an abstraction, which may be implemented in various ways, some being more easily computed with than others. Hence the grammar is sometimes a bit harder to see when described an an implemented structure in some algorithm descriptions. It may also happen, as in [the case of Earley's algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/how-do-i-reconstruct-the-forest-of-syntax-trees-from-the-earley-vector), that the parse forest grammar is derived from a binarized version of the original grammar.

**Bibliography**: search the web with the keywords: *parsing intersection forest* - many papers are open access somewhere.

Some references **on stackexchange**:

- [answer to Algorithms or data structures for dealing with ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903007/algorithms-or-data-structures-for-dealing-with-ambiguity/26132215#26132215)
- [Recovering a parse forest from an Earley parser?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7374/recovering-a-parse-forest-from-an-earley-parser) and [my answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7374/recovering-a-parse-forest-from-an-earley-parser/18006#18006)
- [Complexity of a GLR parser on an ambiguous grammar](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22621/complexity-of-a-glr-parser-on-an-ambiguous-grammar)
- [How do I reconstruct the forest of syntax trees from the Earley vector?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/how-do-i-reconstruct-the-forest-of-syntax-trees-from-the-earley-vector)

Comment: I've been doing my own research into parsers and grammars on the side for the last few years. This answer captures just about everything I've discovered and articulates in an very understandable manner. I'd upvote this three times if I could.

Answer (score 6):

As you correctly note, ambiguity is rampant in natural language and whatever data structure is used for parsing in ambiguous grammars must somehow represent a large number of possible derivations.

Despite this, it's not feasible to represent every possible derivation as an explicit parse tree, because the number of possible bracketings of a string is its [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), exponential in its length.

Which data structure is used to compactly represent ambiguity depends on the parsing algorithm chosen.

I'll use the **[CKY algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm)** as an example, as the way in which it packs ambiguity is simple to describe.

The CKY parsing algorithm implicitly represents ambiguity using a data structure called a chart.

To focus on your question, I'll leave the description of the algorithm out, only describing how the data structure represents ambiguity. I'll leave a description of the algorithm itself to any NLP text or [the video from Chris Manning's Coursera course](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hq80J8kBg-Y).

Suppose we're parsing a sentence with N words. The chart can be modelled as a two-dimensional array, in which each cell C[i,j] contains all non-terminals which words [i..j] of the input sentence can derive.

For instance, in the below chart, cell C[0,3] contains all the non-terminals derivable from the words *Book the flight* using a particular grammar.

[image: CKY chart]

The CKY algorithm builds up the chart bottom-up through [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), so that when the algorithm terminates, the cell C[0,N] contains all possible non-terminals with a yield of the words [0..N].

The key insight that allows the chart to implicitly represent all possible derivations is that any parse tree in which some constituent XP has the yield [i..j] is represented by the very same chart entry in the cell C[i,j].

In the above chart, for example, the chart entry NP in cell C[1,3] implicitly belongs to *every parse tree* in which the words *the flight* at positions 1 and 2 is interpreted as an NP.

If each production rule is associated with a probability (a probabilistic context-free grammar), then a **decoding** algorithm such as the [Viterbi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) can be used to find the most likely parse given the chart.

Other parsing algorithms for [CFGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), such as the Earley algorithm, have analogous ways of packing ambiguity — in an [Earley parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser), for instance, a data structure called the ***agenda*** contains all possible parsing states for a prefix of the input sentence.

It's also possible for a parsing algorithm to discard ambiguity. Since not every possible parse is a likely parse, massive efficiency gains can be realised by only preserving a number of likely parses at each step (a *greedy algorithm*).

Finally, some parsing algorithms, such as the [Chu-Liu-Edmonds algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm) for [MST (minimum spanning tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) parsing, do not really represent derivational ambiguity directly. In such algorithms, the set of all possible parses isn't actually stored and thus can't easily be recovered. Instead, the sentence is treated as a graph, with directed edges representing dependencies between words. A tree algorithm runs over this graph to find the maximum-scoring set of spanning dependency edges.

This is sufficient because most parsing applications in NLP focus not on enumerating all parses, but on finding the best parse with respect to some figure of merit.

Bibliography:

McDonald, Ryan, et al. "Non-projective dependency parsing using spanning tree algorithms." Proceedings of the conference on Human Language Technology and Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing. Association for Computational Linguistics, 2005.

Comment: Actually the problem is worse than stated in your second sentence, as the number of parses can even be infinite. Forgetting this is a recurring error in the parsing literature. It may seem a minor point, but the parsing structures that allow for handling this infinity may play a significant role when you try to parse ill-formed input or noisy input.

Comment: Your statement "*Which data structure is used to compactly represent
ambiguity depends on the parsing algorithm chosen.*" is correct, but
misleading. It is correct because the data structure representation
has to change to fit the implementation logic of the chosen
algorithmic solution. It is misleading because, whatever the algorithm
you consider, afaik, this data structure is always a representation of
the very same abstract concept: a grammar. Hence this dependence is
very superficial, and exists only in representation, not in substance.