# Earley Parser: Ambiguity

Tags: nlp, syntax-trees, parsing, ambiguity

I've got a pretty basic question concerning the Earley parser: In case of syntactic ambiguity ( **S -> NP VP(V NP(NP PP))** vs. **S -> NP VP(VP((V NP) PP)** ), are both parses stored in one chart or in two?

the grammar im talking about is the following:

`S -> VP NP
VP -> V VP
VP -> VP PP
NP -> NP PP
NP -> Det N
PP -> P NP`

so you while parsing could either attach a PP to an NP or to an VP.

my question is detail is how the **graphical chart** would look like, meaning the positions of predict, scan and complete. I was assuming that both parses would be stored in one (big) chart. So S' will then be found in, let's say, s[0][8] and s[0][16] ? Is that right?
An attached image or link with a graphical chart parsing through an ambigous sentence would help.

greetings

Comment: possible duplicate of https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/is-there-a-favoured-data-structure-for-storing-ambiguous-parse-trees-in-natural?

Comment: Can you draw somewhere the trees corresponding to your two examples of parse-tree?

Comment: the tree would look be similiar to this http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3804/8wr3dqog_png.htm

Comment: Thanks for the trees. BTW, you are not supposed to crosspost your questions. If you expect a better answer from CS, you should flag your question and ask to have it migrated to CS. There is also the risk that it will be considered duplicate on CS, as there was a prior question on this topic, which I refer to in my answer.

Comment: Your trees should be represented as: S(NP VP(V NP(NP PP))) and S(NP VP(VP(V NP) PP)) . Even assuming there is a reason for differentiating the top symbol S, you have one open parenthesis too many in the second example.

Answer (score 5):

Earley parser is one example of chart parser, also called dynamic
programming parser. There are many other kinds such as the CYK parser,
the GLR and GLL parser, and more.

The whole point of chart parsing is to build a unique chart that will
mimic all possible parsing computations, since there may be
exponentially many (or even infinitely many in pathological cases). It
is organized so that parts of computations that are common to distinct
parses are somehow shared. This is so effective that the whole
computation is done in cubic time at worst.

The basic chart parser is a recognizer. However the chart can
incorporate a structure that also keep track of the corresponding parse
trees, or more precisely of all parse-trees corresponding to these
computations.

This structure for the parses trees tries to share common subparts (as
the chart does for parsing computation), so that exponentially many
parse trees can actually be represented in a unique structure that has
a cubic size.

So, if I understand your question correctly, the answer is that the
two parse-trees (or as many as there are) are all stored in the same
structure associated to the unique chart.

Such a structure is often called a shared forest, but its organization
can vary a bit, depending on the specific algorithm. The structure
used by Earley's algorithms is not too easy to understand.

For more information, I suggest you look at the question: [Is there a
favoured data structure for storing ambiguous parse trees in Natural
Language Processing?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/is-there-a-favoured-data-structure-for-storing-ambiguous-parse-trees-in-natural)

For a detailed intuitive explanation of how sharing is organized to get an a possibly exponential (or even infinite) number of trees in a cubic structure, you may look at the first 6 pages of this [1991 paper by Lang](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2747609_Towards_a_Uniform_Formal_Framework_for_Parsing). It does contain some simple examples. There are other papers on the web with such examples (I could copy some here, if really needed ... but since they are available with comments ...). One important point to keep in mind is that those diagram give you the a kind of purified version of the basic mechanism. It may be a lot more confused in actual parsers because this is encoded and interacting with the specific parsing process (This is the case for the Earley parser). But describing that is usually much too technical. I discuss a bit, about Earley's parser, in an answer to a question on another SE site: [How do I reconstruct the forest of syntax trees from the Earley vector?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/how-do-i-reconstruct-the-forest-of-syntax-trees-from-the-earley-vector)

Getting an infinite number of trees in a cubic structure should not be too surprising. After all, CF grammar can be pretty small and still represent an infinite number of trees.

*I would have tried to show sharing of subparts in your example, but I do not understand your notation. May be you can explain it: I could not draw trees from what you wrote. What is the + for? What does it mean to have an open parenthesis not preceded by a syntactic category?*

Comment: How exactly are the two parse trees stored in one chart? Can you maybe post an image of a chart with two parse trees integrated? I only found charts with one parse tree.

Comment: @bngschmnd I included a reference available on the web (you may have to register for free). It does contain examples. To understand how it is built by the parsing process, there are other papers.

Comment: @babobu: i edited my first post to make my question clearer.

Comment: @bngschmnd Your modified question is far too detailed in technicalities. First, Earley's parser is not presented graphically in the papers I
read (those written by Earley himself). Another point is that these
technical details do not matter very much. What is important is to
understand the principles that make these techniques work. Teaching
this algorithm is ill advised, because it is too much technical
complexity for probably no benefit. Actually Earley himself does not
say much about keeping the parse trees. Did you look at the references
I gave you? Can you answer your question for CYK.

Comment: I implemented a CKY parser in python. To store multiple parses I used backpointers which store the information how the parse was built so far.

Comment: @bngschmnd Earley parser works pretty much the same as CKY. When a
prefix part of a RHS has been recognized, it stores that in the chart,
and keeps back-pointers in some form to the the subcomponents it used
to do the completion. It is essentially the completer that builds the
tree (as I remember). I say a bit more in the reference I added at the
end of my answer. CKY is a chart parser, and they all more or less
work on the same principes (up to details and optimizations). But most
parsers use structures that less intricate than for Earley, because
they use only binary grammars (CNF is binary)

Comment: @bngschmnd I noticed that you accepted the answer given to you on
cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33227, while you did not accept mine
here. As it turns out, the answer you accepted is a very general
statement on chart parsing, that happens to be not quite right for
only one of the classical parser: Earley's (see comments there on that
issue). I told you as much, since the diagram there is just the
standard CYK matrix, but warned you about Earley. The reason Earley's
algorithm is not presented graphically is probably due to the
intricacies of the chart and the unusual structure of the forest.